# Is this constraint equation written right here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string, constrained-dynamics

[image]

This is a constraint equation he has written here.

This is a trick to solve constraint equations faster.

Now he has made a equation that a2 ( acceleration of 2kg block) and a1(acceleration of 1kg block).

a2 = 2a1.

I have done earlier constant equation by other method.I think it should be wrong since the directions of both acceleration should be different.So it should be  -a2 = 2a1.
But am not if I am right.He has written these statements by saying that work done = tension force * their displacement (of blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question will not be understood by people who don't know this trick you should provide a link or give a short derivation. That being said,

$\sum T.a$ Is the summation of the dot product of the tension force and acceleration you should know that the dot product is the product of their magnitudes and the angle between them.

So the equation he arrived at is the relation between the magnitudes of $a_1$ and $a_2$

Comment: Ok.I understood your point.I did give the way he solved down below but yes I didn’t mention dot product and I think a bit more explanation.

Comment: Do you ask for a bit more explanation? What is it you don't understand yet?

Comment: Since we have got both values positive. How will we know in which direction which block is accelerating.You know , if one comes negative , we know that other block is going to accelerate in the other direction but right now we don’t that for both of them.How to find that then ?

Comment: This formula is not used to find the direction of acceleration only the relation between the magnitudes. We can make the free body diagram equations have only a single variable helping us to solve them. To find the directions we would just have to guess if our guess was wrong we would just have a negative sign indicating our wrong guess.

Comment: Yes.So we actually can’t find direction of acc here right.Our answer can be wrong also if we took different direction.is it not ?.Is it that we can get negative sign in this as well ?

Comment: No no, we take directions to solve the equations , we use this to relate both accelerations. If you get a negative sign while using this formula you must have made a mistake. Negative magnitude is not possible.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @JustJohan

Comment: I have understood it far more better now.